# Upload a file in ASP?

Tags: html, asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUploader ion my website. When I choose a pic, it works fine.
But when I choose another type of file, this error occurs:

> This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.

[image: click to see error]

Here is my code:

```
protected void UploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb_pic.Checked==true)
    {
        UploadPic();
    }
    else if (rb_vid.Checked == true)
    {
        UploadVideo();
    }
    else if (rb_picvid.Checked == true)
    {
        UploadVidPic();
    }

}
```

As you see, `Uploadvideo` method is empty:

```
public void UploadVideo()
{

}
```

`UploadPic();` and `UploadVidPic();` are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i just test it again .
it works for some files . 
but some files still has an error .